# How to make cURL not to show body of requested page?

Tags: php, curl

My code shows the requested page, while i want just to post data to login

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
$login_url = $tt;
$Post_Data = ('username='.$un.'&password='.$pw);
$ch = curl_init();
//
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
//
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'usersCookies/'.$un.'.cookie');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'usersCookies/'.$un.'.cookie');
//
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Post_Data);
//
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
echo $postResult;
//////////////////////////////
```

And then request $serverURI to complete the login,

```
//////////////////////////////
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $serverURI);
$logDO = curl_exec($ch);
echo $logDO;
//////////////////////////////
```

**I don't want to show those pages to user**

i tried this opt: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);` but nothing new.

**What i do to disable BODY in cURL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to show those pages to user

Then why would you echo it ?

Remove this line :

```
echo $postResult;
```

And nothing will be showed to the user. This is provided you by the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` flag you've already set.

---

Using `CURLOPT_NOBODY` won't do it, because CURL would send a `HEAD` request instead of the post you want. 
There's no way to prevent the server from sending you the body, but you can just ignore it.

Comment: @xYuri I'm not really sure I understand your comment here.

Comment: As u see am requesting more than one page, when i comment the echo $postResult; its not login as $postResult execute $ch.
am i wrong?

Comment: Echoing or not a value will not change the fact you're logged in. What will make you logged in is your cookie jar. So, not, you can comment safely and stay logged in.

Comment: Now it not shows the page content, Thanks very much. it was my mistake as 
    `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` was sat to false in the second part of the code.